# R: interaction(): combinations rather than permutations

Tags: r

When using the `interaction()` function in R, 13 and 31 are considered different interactions. I want to consider them to be the same.

```
factor1 <- c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3))
factor2 <- c(rep(c(1,2,3), 3))

combined <- interaction(factor1, factor2, sep = "")
```

*Combined* now looks like this:

```
> combined
[1] 11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33
Levels: 11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
> combined
[1] 11 12 13 12 22 23 13 23 33
Levels: 11 12 13 22 23 33
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort first; and drop levels afterwards:

```
f1 = pmin(factor1, factor2)
f2 = pmax(factor1, factor2)

droplevels(interaction(f1, f2, sep=""))
# [1] 11 12 13 12 22 23 13 23 33
# Levels: 11 12 22 13 23 33
```

If you're fine with a string result, `paste0(f1,f2)` is simpler.